# How to fetch data while where condition in jsonb in Postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, select

I have a table data_table like this

```
| id         | reciever                                     
| (bigint)   |(jsonb)                                      

----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1       | [{"name":"ABC","email":"abc@gmail.com"},{"name":"ABDFC","email":"ab34c@gmail.com"},...]
|    2       | [{"name":"DEF","email":"deef@gmail.com"},{"name":"AFDBC","email":"a45bc@gmail.com"},...]
|    3       | [{"name":"GHI","email":"ghfi@gmail.com"},{"name":"AEEBC","email":"5gf@gmail.com"},...]
|    4       | [{"name":"LMN","email":"lfmn@gmail.com"},{"name":"EEABC","email":"gfg5@gmail.com"},...]
|    5       | [{"name":"PKL","email":"dfdf@gmail.com"},{"name":"ABREC","email":"a4rbc@gmail.com"},...]
|    6       | [{"name":"ANI","email":"fdffd@gmail.com"},{"name":"ABWC","email":"abrtc@gmail.com"},...]
```

when i run on pg admin it works fine

`I want to fetch row by putting email in where condition like select * from data_table where receiver = 'abc@gmail.com'.` there can be more data in array so i have shown "...".

I have tried like `where receiver-->>'email'='abc@gmail.com'` but it is working in the case `{"name":"ABC","email":"abc@gmail.com"} only` not in array where i have to chaeck every email in array

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `exists` and `jsonb_array_elements()`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.receiver) x(elt)
    where x.elt ->> 'email' = 'abc@gmail.com'
)
```

This gives you all rows where at least one element in the array has the given email.

If you want to actually exhibit the matching elements, then you can use a `lateral join` instead (if more than one element in the array has the given email, this duplicates the row):

```
select t.*, x.elt
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.receiver) x(elt)
where x.elt ->> email = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

Comment: ERROR can't extract an element from object @GMB

Comment: @bala if you get that error, then you example you have shown us is not accurate.

Comment: May be i am missing one thing is that in some row when data is single then store d this {"email":"abc@gmail.com"} i mean its not in an array @jjanes

Comment: @bala, the simple answer is "don't store things that way".  You could work around it, but it will be an never ending nightmare.